# Fetch from core data and display it in tableview in swift 5

Tags: ios, core-data, swift5

How to fetch saved data from core data? How to debug it ? I have called the fetch from view will appear..[image]

[image]

Comment: please post formatted code , not screen shots

Comment: @WarrenBurton May I get your email I can post it there?

Comment: Please edit your question and put code formatted text in the question instead of using screen shots. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As per your comments on Ashish's response, it seems like you are not saving the managed object context after inserting the records.

Insertion process:

1. Fresh launch app, initialize core data and insert data in DB
2. Call managedObjectContext.save and check if the save operation is successful or got failure.

Then notify the view controller to refresh the weather list using NSNotification on the main thread or some other mechanism as per your suitability.

And then try to fetch weathers from viewContext for UI rendering.